# Capistrano deployment With rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano, rbenv

I'm currently deploying an app using Capistrano-rbenv. The server where i'm trying to host already has multiple applications setup and running. For ruby version manager rbenv is used, there are multiple versions of ruby setup already and global one is set to ruby "1.8.7". The current application that i'm deploying now uses ruby 2.1.5. I have installed the required ruby version, and when I try to deploy w.r.t the environment the releases happen but when the assets:precompile happens there is an issue. While precompiling the bundler gem is taken from the global gem set version, and not taking from 2.1.5 ruby gems. Below I have mentioned the error along with my current setup.

```
 error:
         /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.8.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18

deploy.rb setup

# Server
# set :default_environment, {
#   path: '/home/deployer/.rbenv/shims:/home/deployer/.rbenv/bin',
#   rbenv_root: '/home/deployer/.rbenv'
# }

set :user, 'deployer'
set :rbenv_type, :user
#set :bundle_dir, "/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0"
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.5'
# set :rbenv_ruby_dir, '/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5'
# set :bundle_cmd, "#{release_path}/bin/bundle"
# set :rbenv_custom_path, '/home/deployer/.rbenv'
set :rbenv_path, '/home/deployer/.rbenv'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
```

But when I try bundling from the releases folder at any of the one release, it runs fine without any errors. What am I doing wrong ?

I cannot set the 2.1.5 as global on the server as many other apps depend on it.

Any Advise would be helpful.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about create a `.ruby-version` file in your app path?

```
cd /path/to/app/
echo 2.1.5 > .ruby-version
ruby -v
bundle install
```

Check in the changes and try to deploy it again.

Comment: tried that as well now use. But the problem with Capistrano-rails gem which I had used in my app, due to some reason it was not letting me select the path. But any ways thanks for your suggestion.